# Aggregate cost for a directed graph in Prolog

Tags: beginner, prolog

I've come up with a simple graph traversal algorithm to calculate the aggregated cost of a directed graph or its subgraphs. Given a directed graph, the code visits all reachable nodes and sums up the cost related to the node paying attention to already visited nodes. The return value is the total cost of (sub)graph.

For example, for the graph embedded in the code below all the following is true:

```
graphCost(a, 63).
graphCost(b, 26).
graphCost(c, 60).
graphCost(f, 32).
```

As you can see, I wasn't able to avoid duplicated paths without using global variables. I'm new to Prolog, so would like to have someone more experienced to look at it and check whether or not it's reasonable. Perhaps there's a ready to use function to do the same? Is there a more effective way to do it?

```
edge(a,b).
edge(a,c).
edge(b,d).
edge(c,d).
edge(d,e).
edge(b,b).
edge(c,f).

cost(a, 1).
cost(b, 2).
cost(c, 4).
cost(d, 8).
cost(e, 16).
cost(f, 32).

visitAndMove2(A) :-
  \+edge(A, _),
  nb_getval('Visited', Visited),
  ( \+member(A, Visited) ->
    nb_setval('Visited', [A | Visited]),
    cost(A, C),
    nb_getval('Cost', Cost),
    TC is Cost + C,
    nb_setval('Cost', TC),
    write(' --> '), write(A), write(': '), writeln([A | Visited])
  ;
    write(A), writeln(' --|')).

visitAndMove2(A) :-
  edge(A, Child),
  A \== Child,
  nb_getval('Visited', Visited),
  \+member(Child, Visited),
  nb_setval('Visited', [Child | Visited]),
  cost(Child, C),
  nb_getval('Cost', Cost),
  TC is Cost + C,
  nb_setval('Cost', TC),
  write(A), write(' --> '), write(Child), write(': '), writeln([Child | Visited]),
  visitAndMove2(Child).

graphCost(A, Cost) :-
  nb_setval('Visited', [A]),
  cost(A, C),
  nb_setval('Cost', C),
  visitAndMove2(A),
  nb_getval('Cost', Cost).
```

Answer (score 1):

Using global variables is a sure sign that you are not working within the declarative paradigm. A *declarative way* to solve this is to keep track of the already visited variables via an **argument** of your predicate.

Also, `please_use_a_readable_naming_convention` `insteadOfMakingEverythingHardToReadAsInJava`.

For example, suppose you have a relation `visited_and_move(Vs0, Vs, Vertex0, Vertex)`, where:

- `Vs0` is the list of vertices that are already visited
- `Vs` is the *next* list of such vertices
- `Vertex0` is the previous vertex
- `Vertex` is the *next* vertex.

This is only an example; you may not need all arguments. However, the general approach should be clear: Think in terms of **relations** between entities, such as the *relation* between a previous list and the next one.

Such pure predicates can be used in *all directions*, and tested in isolation *without* needing to store an implicit global state.

Comment: Yes, I tried that with `Visited` nodes and `Accumulated` cost much like in one of the [Prolog tutorials](https://www.cpp.edu/~jrfisher/www/prolog_tutorial/2_15.html). The trouble was that I wasn't able to get the true total cost because backtracking removed some of the leaf nodes of my `Visited`list (your `Vs0`). For a certain path I wasn't able to pass the complete `Visited` list which would then be used to search sibling paths. I can share my previous attempt which does not work, if you like.

Comment: Just to let you know, I added some explanation about my issue to [my StackOverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37410557/752580).